# Rails, send arrays of model IDs via checkboxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-4, checkbox

I have three html tables that represents models and each line has checkbox.

There is one model that has `has_and_belongs_to_many` association with other three models. I want assign models by checkboxes. My idea is to send ids of selected models to controller.

Is it possible to send to controller array of selected ids via checkboxes and avoiding unchecked ones? So when in action of controller i could do something like that:

```
def action
   table1_ids = params['table1']
   table2_ids = params['table2']
   table3_ids = params['table3']

   table1_ids each do |id|
   #some action
   end

   table2_ids each do |id|
   #some action
   end

   table3_ids each do |id|
   #some action
   end
end
```

My view:

```
<%= form_for @player, {url: {:action => :add_details}, method: :post} do |f| %>

# some static html
<% @bases.each do |basis| %>
                <tr>

                  <td><%= **PLACE OF CHECKBOX** %></td>
                  <td><%= image_tag basis.image_url(:thumb), class: 'thumbnail' %></td>
                  <td><%= basis.name %></td>
                  <td><%= basis.short_info %></td>
                  <% end %>
                </tr>
            <% end %>
```

Comment: more info is needed. Show your views please and explain a little more on what you want to accomplish

Comment: I have added more info

Answer (score 0):

In your params, you'll receive only the IDs of checked items, so the controller actually performs a two-step process. I have Gallery, Entry, and Photo, like

```
Gallery
  has_many :entries
  has_many :photos, :through => :entries
```

and use checkboxes to select photos for a gallery. When updating

```
@gallery = Gallery.find(params[:id])
photo_ids = params[:photo_ids]
photo_ids ||= []
@gallery.entries.each do |entry|
  photo_id = entry.photo_id.to_s
  if !photo_ids.include?(photo_id)
    # existing photo isn't selected anymore
    entry.delete
  else
    # photo is already selected, remove from selected list
    photo_ids.delete(photo_id)
  end
end
photo_ids.each do |photo_id|
  # make a new entry for additions to gallery
  entry = new Entry()
  entry.gallery_id = @gallery.id
  entry.photo_id = photo_id
  entry.save
end
```

Comment: What do I need to write on `<%= **PLACE OF CHECKBOX** %>` place of my html.erb?